# gtest/gmock matcher for subsequence between a pair of iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, googletest, googlemock

Suppose I have a mock function with a signature as follows

```
class MyMock
{
  MOCK_METHOD4( f, void( X, Iterator begin, Iterator end, Y ) );
};
```

I want to write an `EXPECT_CALL` that has the effect of using `ContainerEq`, `ElementsAre` or any other container matcher on the sequence `[begin, end)`.  Ideally something like a 'Range' matcher would exist, e.g.:

```
MyMock m;
EXPECT_CALL( m, f(_,_,_,_) ).With(Args<1,2>(Range(ElementsAre(a,b,c)));
```

Is there such a thing?  How could I make one that allows using all of the various container matches to be used without rewriting them?

Comment: Is there a way to make the Googlemock matchers applicable to `boost::range`?  That might provide the bridge necessary...

Answer (score 3):

Such `IteratorRange` will work in most cases - for limitation look into matcher body:

```
MATCHER_P(IteratorRange, param, "")
{
    auto begin = get<0>(arg);
    auto end = get<1>(arg);

    // these two lines might be weak point of this matcher implementation...
    // I mean:
    //   1. constructing vector might be not supported 
    //       e.g. object are not copyable)
    //   2. copying objects from range might "change"  the tested code behavior
    //       e.g. copy is badly implemented
    //   3. it is for sure "performance" degradation 
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<decltype(begin)>::value_type;
    std::vector<value_type> range{begin, end};

    Matcher<decltype(range)> matcher = param;
    return matcher.MatchAndExplain(range, result_listener);
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
TEST(A,A)
{
    int a,b,c;
    std::vector<int> values{  a,b,c };
    MyMock m;
    EXPECT_CALL( m, f(_,_,_,_) ).With(Args<1,2>(IteratorRange(ContainerEq(values))));
    m.f(X{}, values.begin(), values.end(), Y{});
}
```

---

**[UPDATE]**

The overcome the drawbacks of this internal copying a range into container - you need to invent the light container - like this one:

```
template <typename Iterator>
class RangeView
{
public:
    using iterator = Iterator;
    using const_iterator = Iterator;
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;

    RangeView(Iterator begin, Iterator end) : beginIter(begin), endIter(end) {}

    iterator begin() const { return beginIter; }
    iterator end() const { return endIter; }
    std::size_t size() const { return std::distance(beginIter, endIter); }

    bool operator == (const RangeView& other) const
    {
        return size() == other.size() && std::equal(beginIter, endIter, other.beginIter);
    }

private:
    Iterator beginIter, endIter;
};
```

Plus some helper function to make it easier to use this class:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void PrintTo(RangeView<Iterator> const& range, std::ostream* os)
{
    *os << "{";
    for (auto&& e: range) *os << "[" << PrintToString(e) << "]";
    *os << "}";
}

template <typename Iterator>
RangeView<Iterator> makeRangeView(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    return RangeView<Iterator>(begin, end);
}

template <typename Container>
auto makeRangeView(Container const& container)
{
    return makeRangeView(std::begin(container), std::end(container));
}
```

Note that if you use boost in your project - you can use [range from boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) - you do not need to "reinvent the wheel".

Then - light matcher can be defined without these drawbacks:

```
MATCHER_P(IteratorRangeLight, param, "")
{
    auto begin = get<0>(arg);
    auto end = get<1>(arg);
    auto range = makeRangeView(begin, end);

    Matcher<decltype(range)> matcher = param;
    return matcher.MatchAndExplain(range, result_listener);
}
```

Then - use it like this:

```
TEST(A,A)
{
    int a=1,b=2,c=3;
    std::vector<int> values{  a,b,c };
    MyMock m;
    EXPECT_CALL( m, f(_,_,_,_) ).
With(Args<1,2>(IteratorRangeLight(ContainerEq(makeRangeView(values)))));
//                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// note that you need to use  makeRangeView also within the matcher
    m.f(X{}, values.begin(), values.end(), Y{});
}
```

Comment: Making a copy is the only solution I was able to come up with too - and I didn't like it for the same reasons as you mention in the commented lines...  perhaps using `reference_wrapper` or similar would help?

Comment: Whoa, quick work @PiotrNycz!  I had tried using boost::range but gave up after not being able to decipher the compile error I got... This looks good... I'll give it a try! Thanks.